# Justify list-item makes big gaps beneath them. Not working as it should

Tags: html, css

The problem is that the `ul.horizontal` doesn't work as it should. There is a big gap beneath it and the text-inputs can't retain their 100% width property.

How can I fix this?

```
<ul class="form">
<li>
    <label>Firstname</label> <span>
    <input  name="title" type="text" placeholder="What is your">

</li>

<li>
    <ul class="horizontal">
        <li>
            <label>Beskrvning</label>
            <input  name="title" type="text" placeholder="Why does CSS work with fake tags?">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Beskrvning</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Why does CSS work with fake tags?">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Firstname</label>
            <input  name="title" type="text" placeholder="Why does CSS work with fake tags?">
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

css

```
    ul.form {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
}
li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
li:last-child {
    border:0;
}
label {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:5px 10px;
    position:absolute;
}
input {
    width:100%;
    padding:25px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:none;
    float:left;
    background:none;
}
li:before, li:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
li:after {
    clear:both;
}
ul.horizontal {
    border:none;
    border-radius:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: justify
}
ul.horizontal::after {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    content:".";
    visibility: hidden
}
ul.horizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
    border:none;
    padding-left:40px;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.horizontal li:first-child {
    border-left:none;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large gap is coming from your `ul.horizontal::after` (which incidentally I think should only have one colon, yes?), because you have a period in there with display block and a hidden visibility.  Comment out the visibility and you can see the period.  Simply changing the visibility to hidden does not free up the space it was in on the DOM.  You could consider making it a height of 1px if you absolutely have to have it?

I took that out, and saw how your fields broke in terms of 50/50 layout like you want.  It will be a little tricky getting a 2-column and a 3-column tabular layout with CSS with inner elements (the inputs) at 100% without using tables.  Since that wasn't really the question I just added a quick class for a `three-col` horizontal UL so we could get rid of that massive space under your horizontal ULs.

http://jsfiddle.net/TLMWa/

Hope this helps!